# Number of Intersection points between lower half of an ellipse and a circle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, plane-geometry

An ellipse has its axes parallel to the coordinate system axes and its major axes is parallel to X-axis.

Meanwhile, there is a circle located at the coordinate system origin, whose radius is smaller than the semi major of the ellipse.

Now a curve is constructed as the lower half of the said ellipse.

How do I find out how many intersection points will exist between the circle and the curve?  The general case can be 1 point, 2 points and 3 points (shown in the figures below). **Is it possible to have 4 intersection points?**

[image]

Comment: How do you have 3 intersections when the curve is only the lower half of the ellipse?

Comment: It happens when the half ellipse has the lowest point tangent to the circle and the curve curves up.

Comment: Ah, I would like to ask about this curvature. The curvature of the ellipse is constantly changing. I guess we have to prove that the curvature is always smaller than the circle?

Comment: No, I don't see 3 pionts of intersection on the plot, unless the minor axis is along the X direction. I would like to send you a picture, but I don't know how to do it with "comment".

If you don't mind, I do like to get technical on this.  So to prove that in a neighborhood around the lowest point there will be no other intersection points, we have to first calculate the curvature of the curve and examine if in [-r, r], where r is the radius of the circle, the curvature is always smaller than the curvature of the circle, right?

Comment: @Lee Three intersections on the lower half is perfectly possible. I just did it in Geogebra. The measurements from Geogebra (unfortunately only with $2$ decimals) are: $r=4$, foci of the ellipse $(7,-3)$ and $(-2.59,-2.99)$, and the semi-major is $4.85$.

Comment: @Lee Fair enough. Let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Hello, no, I never meant the center of the ellipse should be on y-axis. That is why I never described it. I just thought when the lower part of the ellipse has 4 points of intersection with the circle, it may be most possible that its center point would be on y-axis.

Comment: Even if it’s not centered on the origin, is the ellipse axis-aligned?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have 4 intersection points. Take for instance four points on the half-ellipse symmetric around the minor axis and the circle passing through them. But non-symmetric solutions are also possible.

[image]

Comment: The semi major of the ellipse should be larger than the radius of the circle.

Comment: In the first version of your question you wrote that the ***major*** axis of the ellipse is larger than the radius of the circle. I'll think about your new request.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is of intersection between two conics of second order. Let us consider the total number
r of points of intersection comprehensively.

Apart from zero number of intersections for non-intersecting complex case, you can only have an even number of real intersection points either two or four, while solving for their solutions.

In tangential case these become correspondingly one or two double points  with discriminant vanishing for a double root.

You cannot have odd number of real intersections no matter where you draw them in the $(x,y)$ plane. If you draw your right figure *fully* you would encounter one more intersection at right in your diagram.

[image]

Comment: I would like to study the lower half of the ellipse only and also the situation where the semi major radius of the ellipse is larger than the radius of the circle.

Comment: I dont get what you want. There can be only *four* four real intersections. You sketched correctly three of them at left, excluding the fourth point, then zooming it at right in a separate sketch including the fourth What else now do you want to study or know next? A table of $(x,y)$ co-ordinates numerically?

Comment: @Narasimham I made the sketch, and if that misled you I apologize. The zoomed-in picture is also showing only 3 intersections. Where do you see the fourth? The other marked point is the center of the ellipse, with the dotted lines indicating the axes are aligned.

Comment: @Steph Fong By the way, feel free to edit over my edit if you don't like it (the picture, the typesetting, etc). You can always do that because you own the question post. Having said that, one must wonder why so many people (including myself) misunderstand your question on the first read. Maybe more things need be changed in the question text to put some emphasis on the key points.

Comment: Hope you see the fourth point that is lost/excluded in the smaller one as you chose a frame outside of the fourth point 4, I labelled  your diagrams with the three points in the zoom and all four points included in the smaller one at left. Hope its OK.

Comment: @Narasimham My curve of interest is the green one in the figure, which is "the lower half of an ellipse". I want to know if it will have 4 points of intersection with the circle. What also should be remembered is that the major axis of the ellipse is parallel to X-axis.

Comment: In the region you defined to be of your interest there are 3 out of 4 total number of points of intersection.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but the origin (purple point labeled $o$) is  NOT in view in the zoomed-in figure on the right. That intersection of the dotted line with the $y$-axis is just the $y$-coordinate of the center of the ellipse.

Comment: Ok, shown frame in red, point 4 lies outside.the frame and other corrections..